# Convert Range of Cells into One Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a database of car part numbers in Excel 2010. I want to simplify the list from this: (ex.)

```
Part Number|Year|Make|Model|Sub-model|Engine

  12345|1990|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  12345|1991|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  12345|1992|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  54321|2001|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  54321|2002|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  54321|2003|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
```

to this:

```
Part Number|Year|Make|Model|Sub-model|Engine

  12345|1990-1992|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
  54321|2001-2003|Ford|Focus|   blah  |blah
```

Besides manually that is. The reason I need this is I'm dealing with like 200,000+ entries for one brand of parts. I'm wondering is there an easy way to do this? I already used kutools for excel to split it into separate workbooks based on make and model if that helps. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: For this, i think you will have to deal with Macros ! and be carefull, Excel is not a database, just a doc, with some more or less useful additional features ;)

Comment: Are the `Part Numbers` unique? I'm assuming they are, yes? And by unique, I mean, say `12345`, it's the same `Sub-model` and `Engine` for all `12345`. Or can there be different `Sub-models` and `Engines` per `Part Number`? I know the answer is pretty obvious, but based on your reply, I can think of one or two solutions.

Comment: part numbers are unique, but i put sub-models in different worksheets, and engines aren't always the same for the given sub-model. So if i open folder Acura, go into Integra workbook, i have worksheets that are Base, LS, GS-R, etc. However, chevy, for example, had the c10 pickup with base sub-model and 3 different engines, sometimes overlapping years.

Comment: A bit more complicated than expected. If `Engine` is different for `Part Number` should they still be merged or should the merging only happen when column entries besides the year are **exactly** the same?

Comment: It is very complicated, unfortunately. The merging to a year - year format should only happen if all other columns are the same. so 12345 1966-1967 chevy c10 pickup base 3.8l is seperate from 12345 1966-1967 chevy c10 pickup base 4.1l. thanks for the help. if i have to, i can separate the data even further, but by then, using a macro or something seems almost useless as ive narrowed it completely. ha.

Comment: No worries, I understand. So basically, the columns have to be exactly the same save for year. I'll see what I can do. If there were no `Sub-model` or `Engine`, this can be solved with one simple formula. ;) Anyway, here's to hoping someone can resolve it quicker than I do.

Comment: well, the sub- model is in seperate sheets in the model's workbook. the engine has been my biggest pain, however i have it branched like this right now: Make Folder->Model Workbook->Sub-Model Worksheet. I could further simplify it to Make Folder->Model Folder->Sub-Model Workbook->Engine Worksheet and run your simple formula on each worksheet then. Maybe after that make a macro that loops through each folder and applies the formula to every worksheet. what do you think?

Comment: Actually, I think I just answered it without going VBA. Not sure how this is going to perform though. See my answer below.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the data is already sorted AND that there are no holes in it, e.g., you would not have a part that was for Ford Focus 1990-1993 and 1995 (but NOT 1994), etc.??

Comment: i didnt think of that until i read your comment. Yes the data is already sorted and i can go to the point of engines are separate worksheets or even partnumbers after that. Unfortunately, there is data with these "holes" as some vehicles didn't have certain engines for certain years or the part just doesn't fit certain years, e.g., it fits 1968-1969 and 1972-1975 chevy pickup, but not 1970-1971. Therefore, the array formula would not be 100% accurate as i just tried it and it read 1990-1998 when no record of 1992 was entered. And to think it was all solved. bummer. what are my options now?

Comment: @user3059444: Is it possible for you to upload a sample file online and post a link here? If there are private details, remove/modify them as you see fit. This is an itch I want to resolve. ;)

Comment: ha. here is the link to the camaro workbook i was about to start. I have NOT made sure all duplicates are removed and that the list is sorted (i sort by pn, eng, then year) nor has it been narrowed to engine on the worksheets. also, the blank worksheet is the base sub-model. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-w8LCqidX1DWk1LUnFPZ0gxOXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @BK201 Did you figure anything out or would it just be simpler to go ahead and continue as i have been doing it manually?

Comment: @user3059444: Still working on it. No promises though, as this is one cookie I think only mehow or Sid can really resolve without hitches. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat lengthy formula can actually solve this. See my image below:

[image]

The best part about this is that it's kind of a search button as well. You just have to change the Part Number, Make, Model, Sub-model, or Engine and it will find the minimum and maximum year that fit your conditions.

The formula for cell `I2` in my image is:

```
=CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$7=H2)*($C$2:$C$7=J2)*($D$2:$D$7=K2)*($E$2:$E$7=L2)*($F$2:$F$7=M2),$B$2:$B$7))," - ",MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$7=H2)*($C$2:$C$7=J2)*($D$2:$D$7=K2)*($E$2:$E$7=L2)*($F$2:$F$7=M2),$B$2:$B$7)))
```

This is an array formula so use **Ctrl-Shift-Enter** when confirming it. Modify the ranges accordingly.

The only downside here is that your sheet can take a massive calculation hit. This can only work so well after a few thousand rows depending on your machine.

Let me know if this works. I'll still work on a VBA one.

EDIT:

Only Part Number as condition:

```
=CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$7=H2),$B$2:$B$7))," - ",MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$7=H2),$B$2:$B$7)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you write the formula to simplify to just Part Number and Year? I could use kutools to change all worksheets to workbooks and sort all engines into separate worksheets into a branch like i mentioned above: Folder(Name:Make)/Folder(Name:Moldel)/Workbook(Name:Sub-Model)/Worksheet(Name:Engine)

Comment: @user3059444: Just to be clear, you only want the `Part Number` to be the condition now? :)

Comment: correct. after simplifying to engines as the different worksheets rather than stopping at submodel. So now in each worksheet the only columns that will have different values as you go down will be part number. and year, obviously.

Comment: Edited the above. Please check. It's also an array formula so don't forget **Ctrl-Shift-Enter**. :)

Comment: Works Great! I can now edit the worksheets to Engine as the last Sorting factor and use the second formula. Thank You! Just thought of something as not all records are the same number of rows, i further edited the range to be entire A column and entire B column: =CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(($A:$A=H2),$B:$B))," - ",MAX(IF(($A:$A=H2),$B:$B)))

Comment: If you read the comments in the question, it has been found that this answer does not 100% work for my situation. However, it was very helpful and may help someone else. thank you.

Comment: @user3059444: No worries. As said in the first comment, a macro will do this perfectly, and not really a formula, unless someone invests in a complex formula. :) One of the best things I can think of is a dictionary, but this level deep, I'm starting to have some thoughts about using that as well.

Comment: how about using conditional formatting/sort/array formula/macro to highlight those non-consecutive data pieces, sort the columns by color, use your array only on the years needing to be grouped, and then maybe the macro to repeat the process. very complex, i would assume. because all i need is the consecutive years to be grouped. I would prefer to do this for simplicity and so my customers see (e.g.)"part fits: 1990-1993, 1995-1998" instead of "part fits: 1990,1991,1992,1993,1995,1996,1997,1998.